# Mint 12, workspaces and two screens

Tags: gnome, linux-mint, workspaces

I have two screens connected to my machine, using the *NVIDIA X Server Settings* program I set them up with *TwinView*.

I had the same exact set up in *Mint 11* and it all worked well, today after switching to *Mint 12* the workspace only affect one screen, not both.
That is, if I switch to another workspace only one screen is showing the new workspace and the other one always stays with the same content.

Any idea why? And how I can resolve this?

Comment: Are you using gnome? if so its a known problem and a fix may not happen.

Comment: Yes, I am using gnome, sorry I forgot to mention that.. Bad news to learn about that, do you have any reference for that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: i ran into this when working with two monitors in gnome. long story short, they made a default and didn't display a gui option of changing it. http://gregcor.com/2011/05/07/fix-dual-monitors-in-gnome-3-aka-my-workspaces-are-broken/

Comment: Yeah, after writing my comment I searched and got to that blog post, it did have a work around which helped, I just got back from restarting the machine and it now works as I want it to. Thanks.